# While I use bs4 to parse site

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I want to parse the price information in Bitmex using bs4.

(The site url is 'https://www.bitmex.com/app/trade/XBTUSD')

So, I wrote down the code like this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.bitmex.com/app/trade/XBTUSD'
bitmex = requests.get(url)

if bitmex.status_code == 200:
    print("connected...")
else:
    print("Error...")

bitmex_html = bitmex.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(bitmex_html , 'lxml' )
price = soup.find_all("span", {"class": "price"})
print(price)
```

And, the result is like this

```
connected...
[]
```

Why '[]' poped up? and To bring the price text like '6065.5', what should I do?
The text I want to parse is

```
<span class="price">6065.5</span>
```

and the selector is

## content > div > div.tickerBar.overflown > div > span.instruments.tickerBarSection > span:nth-child(1) > span.price

I just study Python, so question can seems to be odd to pro...sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty close. Give the following a try and see if it's more what you wanted. Perhaps the format you seeing or retrieving is not quite what you expect. Hope this is helpful.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import sys
import json

url = 'https://www.bitmex.com/app/trade/XBTUSD'
bitmex = requests.get(url)

if bitmex.status_code == 200:
    print("connected...")
else:
    print("Error...")
    sys.exit(1)

bitmex_html = bitmex.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(bitmex_html , 'lxml' )

# extract the json text from the returned page
price = soup.find_all("script", {"id": "initialData"})
price = price.pop()

# parse json text
d = json.loads(price.text)

# pull out the order book and then each price listed in the order book
order_book = d['orderBook']
prices = [v['price'] for v in order_book]
print(prices)
```

Example output:

```
connected...
[6045, 6044.5, 6044, 6043.5, 6043, 6042.5, 6042, 6041.5, 6041, 6040.5, 6040, 6039.5, 6039, 6038.5, 6038, 6037.5, 6037, 6036.5, 6036, 6035.5, 6035, 6034.5, 6034, 6033.5, 6033, 6032.5, 6032, 6031.5, 6031, 6030.5, 6030, 6029.5, 6029, 6028.5, 6028, 6027.5, 6027, 6026.5, 6026, 6025.5, 6025, 6024.5, 6024, 6023.5, 6023, 6022.5, 6022, 6021.5, 6021, 6020.5]
```

Comment: Umm...After reading your answer, I don't know after '''price = soup.find_all("script", {"id": "initialData"})'''. Could you explain it in more detail? Actually, I wanted only present price...Sorry to bother you.

Comment: No bother at all. Maybe when you are looking at the webpage in the browser you are seeing only one price, but when we try to parse it we find that the data are actually in a javascript structure. We can load that wiht json, but find there are more than one price. You'll need to check which one you want. Perhaps having all the prices is more powerful anyway. Print the entire order_book to see the full content. Best of success. Bitmex seems an interesting service.

Comment: I use Devtool in Chrome, but can't find "script", {"id": "initialData"} in element tab. Where can I find that? soup.find_all("script", {"id": "initialData"}) means 'find all thing which tag name is "script" and id is "initialData".'. Am I right? And also, I don't know what ".pop" is...

Comment: Try print(soup) to see what the python script is receiving, there you'll see the reference to initialData. Find_all() locates and returns all occurrences as you describe, as a list and pop() returns the first element from the list. Using .find(..) instead might be enough.

Comment: Aha! Now I understand why I confused. When I open DevTools(pressing F12) in Chrome, I can't find "id : initialData" in Elements tab, but I can find that when i parse in python using bs4. The same contents are located in Sources tab.

Comment: I'll see if there's a way to get 'Elements tab'. Thank you for your sincere reply! I wish you all the best!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the page doesn't contain those `span` elements in first place. If you check the `response` tab in your browser developer tools (press F12 in firefox) you can see that the page is composed of `script` tags with some code written in javascript that creates the elements dynamically when executed.

Since BeautifulSoup can't execute Javascript, you can't extract the elements directly with it. You have two alternatives:

- Use something like `selenium` that allows you to drive a browser from python - that means javascript will be executed because you're using a real browser - however the performance suffers.
- Read the javascript code, understand it and write python code to simulate it. This usually is harder but luckly for you this seem very simple for the page you want:

  ```
  import requests
  import lxml.html

  r = requests.get('https://www.bitmex.com/app/trade/XBTUSD')
  doc = lxml.html.fromstring(r.text)
  data = json.loads(doc.xpath("//script[@id='initialData']/text()")[0])
  ```

As you can see the data is in json format inside the page. After loading the data variable you can use it to access the infomation you want:

```
for row in data['orderBook']:
    print(row['symbol'], row['price'], row['side'])
```

Will print:

```
('XBTUSD', 6051.5, 'Sell')
('XBTUSD', 6051, 'Sell')
('XBTUSD', 6050.5, 'Sell')
('XBTUSD', 6050, 'Sell')
```

Comment: @KunC selenium has advantages and disadvantages. If the javascript is simple enough, it is better to write python code to simulate it since it will probably perform better than launching a full-fledged web browser and executing the javascript. For that bitmex page in your quesiton I wouldn't use selenium because the data is already easily available in javascript/json format and python can read json easily

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much for your help. I envy you that you can get information easily from Bitmex site...haha:)